# Wireguard Android: How to configure secondary DNS?

Tags: vpn, dns

I'm using the official Wireguard app and configured a DNS Server in the app that is only reachable via the VPN. How can I configure a Fallback DNS when the VPN connection is not working or the DNS is not reachable? If I add a second DNS as a comma separated list, both DNS seem to be used randomly. Some apps use the first element others the second, but I like to use the second DNS only as a fallback.